# React typescrpt, how to store first item of array of objects from api response in state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I have a function that makes an API call

```
  async function handleBlur(item: string) {
    const { data } = await apiGateway.getItems(item);
    data && setItem(data[0]);
  }
```

I'm trying to set the first item in state like this

```
  const [item, setItem] = useState<{}>();
```

I'm getting the following typescript error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'GetItemsResponse'.
> Property '0' does not exist on type 'GetItemsResponse'.

I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: pls share minimum reproducable example

Comment: Can you post the type of ```data```? It has to match with the generic type of useState, but your type for useState is an empty object without properties, and I'm sure that's not what you receive from your API gateway.